# How can one adjust the brightness when taking a panorama picture?

Tags: camera, photos, android-12, google-pixel-6

I use Google Pixel 6 with Android 12. I don't see where to adjust the brightness when taking a panorama picture. How can one adjust the brightness when taking a panorama picture?

Answer (score 0):

Reddditu user [MarsR0ver_](https://www.reddit.com/user/MarsR0ver_) [mentioned](https://redd.it/s1zar5) it is currently not possible to adjust the brightness when taking a panorama picture:

> You can't. Just another small detail that will piss you off. Expect more.